# Error iOS after update Flutter to version 3.10.0

Tags: ios, flutter

After update Flutter to version 3.10.x, all my project code run in iPhone error like below. I have check with "Flutter Doctor" all check is no problem. even create a new flutter project run in iOS error too. I have find and try with many solution, but if downgrade to 3.7 it worked.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2023-07-06 13:02:56.076 xcodebuild[22219:218821] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
2
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:800166DA-CB72-4A20-BE70-7D17A091A28D, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:      /var/folders/cn/qp_12tv102j5blhmp_p43zn80000gn/T/flutter_tools.4acIQd/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirzyOVmy/temporary_xcresult_bundle
../../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:50:7: Error: Switch case may fall through to the next case.
          case 'build':
          ^
../../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:55:7: Error: Switch case may fall through to the next case.
          case 'embed':
          ^
../../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:57:7: Error: Switch case may fall through to the next case.
          case 'embed_and_thin':
          ^
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    note: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/cn/qp_12tv102j5blhmp_p43zn80000gn/T/flutter_tools.4acIQd/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirzyOVmy/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
Exited
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps :

1. flutter clean
2. Manually delete podfile.lock and pubspec.lock file.
3. flutter pub get
4. cd ios
5. pod install --repo-update
6. pod install

Try to run again, your problem should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure solution, but I have try run:
flutter pub cache repair

[Follow this solution](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-fatal-error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found/)